# I have a timer I'm trying to get the remaining time to display in the document.title. I cannot figure out how to get this to work

Tags: javascript, html

I have this code which is my timer.

```
const FULL_DASH_ARRAY = 283;
const WARNING_THRESHOLD = 10;
const ALERT_THRESHOLD = 5;

const COLOR_CODES = {
  info: {
    color: "green"
  },
  warning: {
    color: "orange",
    threshold: WARNING_THRESHOLD
  },
  alert: {
    color: "red",
    threshold: ALERT_THRESHOLD
  }
};
let minutes = 120;
let TIME_LIMIT = minutes;
let timePassed = 0;
let timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT;
let timerInterval = null;
let remainingPathColor = COLOR_CODES.info.color;
let isRunning = false;

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
<div class="base-timer">
  <svg class="base-timer__svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g class="base-timer__circle">
      <circle class="base-timer__path-elapsed" cx="50" cy="50" r="45"></circle>
      <path
        id="base-timer-path-remaining"
        stroke-dasharray="283"
        class="base-timer__path-remaining ${remainingPathColor}"
        d="
          M 50, 50
          m -45, 0
          a 45,45 0 1,0 90,0
          a 45,45 0 1,0 -90,0
        "
      ></path>
    </g>
  </svg>
  <span id="base-timer-label" class="base-timer__label">${formatTime(
    timeLeft
  )}</span>
</div>
`;
//Start timer button
document.querySelector(".button-start").addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (isRunning) return;
  isRunning = true;
  startTimer();
});
//Enter custom countdown time
document.customForm.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  onTimesUp();
  let minutes = document.getElementById("minutes").value;
  const mins = this.minutes.value;
  TIME_LIMIT = mins * 60;
  document.getElementById("minutes").value = null;
  startTimer();
});
//Reset button
document
  .querySelector(".button-start-reset")
  .addEventListener("click", function () {
    onTimesUp();
    resetTimer();
  });
//Reset timer
function resetTimer() {
  isRunning = false;
  const { alert, warning, info } = COLOR_CODES;
  timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT = 120;
  document.getElementById("base-timer-label").innerHTML = formatTime(timeLeft);
  setCircleDasharray();
  document
    .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
    .classList.remove(warning.color);
  document
    .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
    .classList.remove(alert.color);
  document
    .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
    .classList.add(info.color);
}
//Times up
function onTimesUp() {
  clearInterval(timerInterval);
}
//Start timer
function startTimer() {
  timePassed = 0;
  timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
    timePassed = timePassed += 1;
    timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT - timePassed;
    document.getElementById("base-timer-label").innerHTML = formatTime(
      timeLeft
    );
    let title = document.getElementById("base-timer-label").innerText;
    document.title = title;
    
    setCircleDasharray();
    setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft);

    if (timeLeft === 0) {
      onTimesUp();
      resetTimer();
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function formatTime(time) {
  const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
  let seconds = time % 60;

  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = `0${seconds}`;
  }

  return `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}

function setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft) {
  const { alert, warning, info } = COLOR_CODES;
  if (timeLeft <= alert.threshold) {
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.remove(warning.color);
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.add(alert.color);
  } else if (timeLeft <= warning.threshold) {
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.remove(info.color);
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.add(warning.color);
  }
}

function calculateTimeFraction() {
  const rawTimeFraction = timeLeft / TIME_LIMIT;
  return rawTimeFraction - (1 / TIME_LIMIT) * (1 - rawTimeFraction);
}

function setCircleDasharray() {
  const circleDasharray = `${(
    calculateTimeFraction() * FULL_DASH_ARRAY
  ).toFixed(0)} 283`;
  document
    .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
    .setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", circleDasharray);
}
```

I am wanting the remaining time to display in the title of my site. I tried

```
let title = document.getElementById("base-timer-label").innerText;
    document.title = title;
```

to no avail. I know this is going to be a simple fix but I'm stuck. Full code below for reference

```js
function reload() {

let sunval = localStorage.getItem("Sunday");
document.querySelector('#Sunday').innerHTML = sunval;
let monval = localStorage.getItem("Monday");
document.querySelector('#Monday').innerHTML = monval;
let tueval = localStorage.getItem("Tuesday");
document.querySelector('#Tuesday').innerHTML = tueval;
let wedval = localStorage.getItem("Wednesday");
document.querySelector('#Wednesday').innerHTML = wedval;
let thuval = localStorage.getItem("Thursday");
document.querySelector('#Thursday').innerHTML = thuval;
let frival = localStorage.getItem("Friday");
document.querySelector('#Friday').innerHTML = frival;
let satval = localStorage.getItem("Saturday");
document.querySelector('#Saturday').innerHTML = satval;
}

let primaryNumber = document.querySelector(".primaryResult");
let primaryPlus = document.querySelector(".buttonPrimaryp");
let primaryMinus = document.querySelector(".buttonPrimarym");
let primaryReset = document.querySelector(".primaryReset");
let primaryTotal = document.querySelector("#primaryTotal");
let units = document.querySelector("#totalUnits");
primaryPlus.addEventListener("click", function () {
  primaryNumber.innerText++;
  let updatedPrimaryNumber = primaryNumber.innerText;
  updatedPrimaryNumber = Math.floor(parseInt(updatedPrimaryNumber) / 9);
  let pUnits = updatedPrimaryNumber;
  primaryTotal.innerText = pUnits;
  units.innerText = Number(primaryTotal.innerText) + Number(secondaryTotal.innerText);
});
primaryMinus.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (primaryNumber.innerText == 0) { document.getElementsByClassName("primaryResult").innerText = "";
  } else {
    primaryNumber.innerText--;
  let updatedPrimaryNumber = primaryNumber.innerText;
  updatedPrimaryNumber = Math.floor(parseInt(updatedPrimaryNumber) / 9);
  let pUnits = updatedPrimaryNumber;
    primaryTotal.innerText = pUnits;
    units.innerText = Number(primaryTotal.innerText) + Number(secondaryTotal.innerText);
  }
});
primaryReset.addEventListener("click", function () {
  primaryNumber.innerText = 0;
  primaryTotal.innerText = primaryNumber.innerText;
  units.innerText = Number(primaryTotal.innerText) + Number(secondaryTotal.innerText);
});

let secondaryNumber = document.querySelector(".secondaryResult");
let secondaryPlus = document.querySelector(".buttonSecondaryp");
let secondaryMinus = document.querySelector(".buttonSecondarym");
let secondaryReset = document.querySelector(".secondaryReset");
let secondaryTotal = document.querySelector("#secondaryTotal");
secondaryPlus.addEventListener("click", function () {
  secondaryNumber.innerText++;
  let updatedSecondaryNumber = secondaryNumber.innerText;
  let sUnits = updatedSecondaryNumber;
    secondaryTotal.innerText = sUnits;
  units.innerText = Number(primaryTotal.innerText) + Number(secondaryTotal.innerText);
});
secondaryMinus.addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (secondaryNumber.innerText == 0) {  document.getElementsByClassName("secondaryResult").innerText = "";
  } else {
    secondaryNumber.innerText--;
    let updatedSecondaryNumber = secondaryNumber.innerText;
  let sUnits = updatedSecondaryNumber;
    secondaryTotal.innerText = sUnits;
    units.innerText = Number(primaryTotal.innerText) + Number(secondaryTotal.innerText);
  }
});
secondaryReset.addEventListener("click", function () {
  secondaryNumber.innerText = 0;
  secondaryTotal.innerText = secondaryNumber.innerText;
  units.innerText = Number(primaryTotal.innerText) + Number(secondaryTotal.innerText);
});

const weekday = [
  "Sunday",
  "Monday",
  "Tuesday",
  "Wednesday",
  "Thursday",
  "Friday",
  "Saturday"
];
const d = new Date();
let day = weekday[d.getDay()];
let id = day;
document.getElementById("buttonSave").addEventListener("click", function () {
  const total = Number(document.getElementById("totalUnits").innerText);
  if (total > 0) {
    document.getElementById(id).innerText = document.getElementById(
      "totalUnits"
    ).innerText;
  } else {
    document.getElementById(id).innerText = "0";
  }
  let sun = document.querySelector('#Sunday').innerText;
  let mon = document.querySelector('#Monday').innerText;
  let tue = document.querySelector('#Tuesday').innerText
  let wed = document.querySelector('#Wednesday').innerText;
  let thu = document.querySelector('#Thursday').innerText;
  let fri = document.querySelector('#Friday').innerText;
  let sat = document.querySelector('#Saturday').innerText;
  localStorage.setItem("Sunday", sun);
  localStorage.setItem("Monday", mon);
  localStorage.setItem("Tuesday", tue);
  localStorage.setItem("Wednesday", wed);
  localStorage.setItem("Thursday", thu);
  localStorage.setItem("Friday", fri);
  localStorage.setItem("Saturday", sat);
});

const FULL_DASH_ARRAY = 283;
const WARNING_THRESHOLD = 10;
const ALERT_THRESHOLD = 5;

const COLOR_CODES = {
  info: {
    color: "green"
  },
  warning: {
    color: "orange",
    threshold: WARNING_THRESHOLD
  },
  alert: {
    color: "red",
    threshold: ALERT_THRESHOLD
  }
};
let minutes = 120;
let TIME_LIMIT = minutes;
let timePassed = 0;
let timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT;
let timerInterval = null;
let remainingPathColor = COLOR_CODES.info.color;
let isRunning = false;

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
<div class="base-timer">
  <svg class="base-timer__svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g class="base-timer__circle">
      <circle class="base-timer__path-elapsed" cx="50" cy="50" r="45"></circle>
      <path
        id="base-timer-path-remaining"
        stroke-dasharray="283"
        class="base-timer__path-remaining ${remainingPathColor}"
        d="
          M 50, 50
          m -45, 0
          a 45,45 0 1,0 90,0
          a 45,45 0 1,0 -90,0
        "
      ></path>
    </g>
  </svg>
  <span id="base-timer-label" class="base-timer__label">${formatTime(
    timeLeft
  )}</span>
</div>
`;
//Start timer button
document.querySelector(".button-start").addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (isRunning) return;
  isRunning = true;
  startTimer();
});
//Enter custom countdown time
document.customForm.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  onTimesUp();
  let minutes = document.getElementById("minutes").value;
  const mins = this.minutes.value;
  TIME_LIMIT = mins * 60;
  document.getElementById("minutes").value = null;
  startTimer();
});
//Reset button
document
  .querySelector(".button-start-reset")
  .addEventListener("click", function () {
    onTimesUp();
    resetTimer();
  });
//Reset timer
function resetTimer() {
  isRunning = false;
  const { alert, warning, info } = COLOR_CODES;
  timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT = 120;
  document.getElementById("base-timer-label").innerHTML = formatTime(timeLeft);
  setCircleDasharray();
  document
    .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
    .classList.remove(warning.color);
  document
    .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
    .classList.remove(alert.color);
  document
    .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
    .classList.add(info.color);
}
//Times up
function onTimesUp() {
  clearInterval(timerInterval);
}
//Start timer
function startTimer() {
  timePassed = 0;
  timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
    timePassed = timePassed += 1;
    timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT - timePassed;
    document.getElementById("base-timer-label").innerHTML = formatTime(
      timeLeft
    );
    let title = document.getElementById("base-timer-label").innerText;
    document.title = title;
    
    setCircleDasharray();
    setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft);

    if (timeLeft === 0) {
      onTimesUp();
      resetTimer();
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function formatTime(time) {
  const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
  let seconds = time % 60;

  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = `0${seconds}`;
  }

  return `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}

function setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft) {
  const { alert, warning, info } = COLOR_CODES;
  if (timeLeft <= alert.threshold) {
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.remove(warning.color);
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.add(alert.color);
  } else if (timeLeft <= warning.threshold) {
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.remove(info.color);
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.add(warning.color);
  }
}

function calculateTimeFraction() {
  const rawTimeFraction = timeLeft / TIME_LIMIT;
  return rawTimeFraction - (1 / TIME_LIMIT) * (1 - rawTimeFraction);
}

function setCircleDasharray() {
  const circleDasharray = `${(
    calculateTimeFraction() * FULL_DASH_ARRAY
  ).toFixed(0)} 283`;
  document
    .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
    .setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", circleDasharray);
}
```

```css
body {
    background: #000000;
    height: 100vh;
    font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, Oxygen,
        Ubuntu, Cantarell, "Open Sans", "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
}

.block-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
}

.primaryResult, .secondaryResult {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
    color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
    font-size: 100px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

button{
    display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

button {
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

button:focus {
    outline: none;
}
.plusminus {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
}
.tile {
    background-color: #000000;
    margin-top: 40px;
    width: 375px;
    height: 425px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    border: solid;
  border-width: 6px;
    border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 20px;
}

.button {
    margin-top: 40px;
    color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
    border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
    font-size: 32px;
}

.buttontimer {
    margin-top: 40px;
    color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
    padding: 4px 10px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
    border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
    font-size: 32px;
}

input {
  display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(65, 65, 95, 0.4);
    color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
    padding: 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
    border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
    color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
  font-size: 16px;
  outline: none;
}

.button:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
}

.buttonPrimaryp, .buttonPrimarym  {
  display: block;
    background-color: rgb(65, 65, 95, 0.4);
  width: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.buttonSecondaryp, .buttonSecondarym {
    display: block;
    background-color: rgb(65, 65, 95, 0.4);
  width: 40px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.primaryReset, .secondaryReset,.buttonReset {
    background-color: rgb(65, 65, 95, 0.4);
    color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
    margin: 12px auto 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 4px 56px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
}

#app {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.button-start {
    background-color: rgb(65, 65, 95, 0.4);
    color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
    margin: 12px auto 0;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
}

.button-start-reset {
    background-color: rgb(65, 65, 95, 0.4);
    color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
    margin: 12px auto 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 4px 56px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
}



.totaltile {
    width: 500px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: solid;
  border-width: 6px;
    border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
    font-size: 32px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#buttonSave {
    background-color: rgb(65, 65, 95, 0.4);
    color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
    margin: 5px 0;
  margin-left: 50px;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 4px 26px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
}

#buttonSave:hover {
    opacity: 0.9;
}

p {
  display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
    color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
    font-size: 32px;
}
#primaryTotal, #secondaryTotal{
  display: none;
}

.base-timer {
  margin-top: 20px;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
}

.base-timer__svg {
    transform: scaleX(-1);
}

.base-timer__circle {
    fill: none;
    stroke: none;
}

.base-timer__path-elapsed {
    stroke-width: 7px;
    stroke: grey;
}

.base-timer__path-remaining {
    stroke-width: 7px;
    stroke-linecap: round;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: center;
    transition: 1s linear all;
    fill-rule: nonzero;
    stroke: currentColor;
}

.base-timer__path-remaining.green {
    color: rgb(65, 184, 131);
}

.base-timer__path-remaining.orange {
    color: orange;
}

.base-timer__path-remaining.red {
    color: red;
}

.base-timer__label {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    font-size: 45px;
    color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
}

.timerpadding {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

::placeholder {
  color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
  text-align: center;
}

.weekdays {
    width: 500px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 4px 10px;
    font-size: 32px;
  color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  
}

.weeklyTotals {
    color: rgb(0, 190, 255);
  font-size: 16px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}

#sun, #mon, #tues, #wed, #thur, #fri, #sat{
  width: 40px;
  height: 80px;
  margin-left: 3px;
  margin-right: 3px;
    padding: 4px 15px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
    border-color: rgb(170, 170, 170, 0.5);
}

#Sunday, #Monday, #Tuesday, #Wednesday, #Thursday, #Friday, #Saturday {
  width: 40px;
  height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<body onload="reload()">
    <div class="block-wrapper">
        <div class="tile">
            <div class="tile-block">
      <div class="primaryResult">0 </div>
        <p>Document Count</p>
                <span class="plusminus">
        <button class="button buttonPrimaryp" type="button">
                    +
                </button>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <button class="button buttonPrimarym" type="button">
                    -
          </button> </span>
                <button class=" button primaryReset">
                    Reset
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tile">
            <div class="tile-block">
        <span class="secondaryResult">0 </span>
                <p>Verified Videos</p>
                <span class="plusminus">
        <button class="button buttonSecondaryp" type="button">
                    +
                </button>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;
        <button class="button buttonSecondarym" type="button">
                    -
          </button> </span>
                <button class="button secondaryReset">
                    Reset
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tile">
            <div class="tile-block">
                <div id="app">
                </div>
        <button class="button buttontimer button-start" type="button">
                    Start Timer
                </button>
        <form name="customForm" id="custom">
        <input type="text" id="minutes" placeholder="Enter Minutes" autocomplete="off">
      </form>
                <button class=" button buttontimer button-start-reset" type="button">
                    Reset
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="./script.js"></script>
    <span class="totaltile">
        <p>Total Units =&nbsp;
            <span id="totalUnits">
                0
            </span>
      <button id="buttonSave">
                    Save Total
                </button>
        </p>
    </span>
  <span id = primaryTotal>0</span>
  <span id = secondaryTotal>0</span>
  <span class="weekTile">
  <div class="weeklyTotals">
  Weekly Totals
  </div>
<div class="weekdays">
  <span id="sun">
    <p>Sun</p>
    <span id="Sunday"> 0 </span>
  </span>
    <span id="mon">
      <p>Mon</p>
      <span id="Monday">0 </span>
  </span>
  <span id="tues">
    <p>Tue</p>
      <span id="Tuesday">0 </span>
  </span>
  <span id="wed">
    <p>Wed</p>
      <span id="Wednesday">0 </span>
  </span>
  <span id="thur">
    <p>Thu</p>
     <span id="Thursday">0 </span>
  </span>
  <span id="fri">
    <p>Fri</p>
      <span id="Friday">0 </span>
  </span>
  <span id="sat">
    <p>Sat</p>
    <span id="Saturday">0 </span>
  </span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score -2):

The code I used is fine I just needed to clear cache.

```
const FULL_DASH_ARRAY = 283;
const WARNING_THRESHOLD = 10;
const ALERT_THRESHOLD = 5;

const COLOR_CODES = {
  info: {
    color: "green"
  },
  warning: {
    color: "orange",
    threshold: WARNING_THRESHOLD
  },
  alert: {
    color: "red",
    threshold: ALERT_THRESHOLD
  }
};
let minutes = 120;
let TIME_LIMIT = minutes;
let timePassed = 0;
let timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT;
let timerInterval = null;
let remainingPathColor = COLOR_CODES.info.color;
let isRunning = false;

document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = `
<div class="base-timer">
  <svg class="base-timer__svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g class="base-timer__circle">
      <circle class="base-timer__path-elapsed" cx="50" cy="50" r="45"></circle>
      <path
        id="base-timer-path-remaining"
        stroke-dasharray="283"
        class="base-timer__path-remaining ${remainingPathColor}"
        d="
          M 50, 50
          m -45, 0
          a 45,45 0 1,0 90,0
          a 45,45 0 1,0 -90,0
        "
      ></path>
    </g>
  </svg>
  <span id="base-timer-label" class="base-timer__label">${formatTime(
    timeLeft
  )}</span>
</div>
`;
//Start timer button
document.querySelector(".button-start").addEventListener("click", function () {
  if (isRunning) return;
  isRunning = true;
  startTimer();
});
//Enter custom countdown time
document.customForm.addEventListener("submit", function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  onTimesUp();
  let minutes = document.getElementById("minutes").value;
  const mins = this.minutes.value;
  TIME_LIMIT = mins * 60;
  document.getElementById("minutes").value = null;
  startTimer();
});
//Reset button
document
  .querySelector(".button-start-reset")
  .addEventListener("click", function () {
    onTimesUp();
    resetTimer();
  });
//Reset timer
function resetTimer() {
  isRunning = false;
  const { alert, warning, info } = COLOR_CODES;
  timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT = 120;
  document.getElementById("base-timer-label").innerHTML = formatTime(timeLeft);
  setCircleDasharray();
  document
    .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
    .classList.remove(warning.color);
  document
    .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
    .classList.remove(alert.color);
  document
    .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
    .classList.add(info.color);
}
//Times up
function onTimesUp() {
  clearInterval(timerInterval);
}
//Start timer
function startTimer() {
  timePassed = 0;
  timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
    timePassed = timePassed += 1;
    timeLeft = TIME_LIMIT - timePassed;
    document.getElementById("base-timer-label").innerHTML = formatTime(
      timeLeft
    );
    let title = document.getElementById("base-timer-label").innerText;
    document.title = title;
    
    setCircleDasharray();
    setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft);

    if (timeLeft === 0) {
      onTimesUp();
      resetTimer();
    }
  }, 1000);
}

function formatTime(time) {
  const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
  let seconds = time % 60;

  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = `0${seconds}`;
  }

  return `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}

function setRemainingPathColor(timeLeft) {
  const { alert, warning, info } = COLOR_CODES;
  if (timeLeft <= alert.threshold) {
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.remove(warning.color);
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.add(alert.color);
  } else if (timeLeft <= warning.threshold) {
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.remove(info.color);
    document
      .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
      .classList.add(warning.color);
  }
}

function calculateTimeFraction() {
  const rawTimeFraction = timeLeft / TIME_LIMIT;
  return rawTimeFraction - (1 / TIME_LIMIT) * (1 - rawTimeFraction);
}

function setCircleDasharray() {
  const circleDasharray = `${(
    calculateTimeFraction() * FULL_DASH_ARRAY
  ).toFixed(0)} 283`;
  document
    .getElementById("base-timer-path-remaining")
    .setAttribute("stroke-dasharray", circleDasharray);
}
```

Comment: There's really no point in keeping this question open as no one else will benefit by having the exact same issue. Clearing your cache is equivalent to having a typo in your code